# REST Api Routes format with filter

Tags: api, design-patterns

I am relatively new to the environment of professional use of API Routes, so a basic question.

Im working with VueJS asFrontend and node Express as Backend. How the GET Request against the api have to look like? I wonder how to deliver filter requests with a REST API?

##### Example:

`GET https://example.com/api/v1/cities` -> get all cities.

`GET https://example.com/api/v1/cities?country={countrId}` -> get all cities from this country with the id = {countrId}.

**Question:** Is this an API antipattern? If so, what would the route look like?

**Note:**
A colleague told me it should look like this:

`GET https://example.com/api/v1/cities?country.id={countrId}`

Comment: REST does not prescribe a particular query string format because it is (supposed to be) transport agnostic. You do what works well for the framework and consumers of your API.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's exactly how I saw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set just `id`, then url could look like this:

```
https://example.com/api/v1/cities/1
```

[Read more about API best practices here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/)

If you have many query string parameters, then it could look like this:

```
https://example.com/api/v1/cities?id=1&location=foo&lang=bar
```

Comment: Hey StepUp! Thank you for your answer and the link. It is good explained. If I have understood this correctly, the query parameter is always a property of the entity, right? I had never seen it that way before. 

If my city has the following properties: `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, country_id INT DEFAULT NULL, name VARCHAR(255)`. 

Then the key is country_id. I always named the entity itself because I only wanted to use the one filter. My question: Is this an anti-pattern or bad?

Comment: @MaxPattern `Is this an anti-pattern or bad?` I think, it is as minimum not good idea to expose to other people your database columns names. It reveals what it is ubder the hood. So it can be concluded that data is not incapsulated. In addition, please, read [RESTful API design best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026860/restful-api-design-best-practices)